# C# Get process full location if process has administrative privileges

Tags: c#, process

I developed a test c# app with a button, when you click the button, it checks an active process, and then it prints it's full location.
Everything works fine, until you run that other program as administrator (Right Click "Run As Administrator")
Then I get exception here: full_location = proc.MainModule.FileName;

Is there a way to get location of a process with administrative priviledges?
If I compile the app with app.manifest "requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" , then it works even for processes run as administrator.
But is there a way for non-administrative priviledges?

The code that I use:

```
    private void btn_test_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string full_location = "";
        Process[] theprocesses = Process.GetProcessesByName("NT037");//That particular program name

        foreach (Process proc in theprocesses)
        {
            full_location = proc.MainModule.FileName;//<-- An unhandled exception of type 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception' occurred in System.dll


            Console.WriteLine(full_location + " (NT037)");                
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are trying to get information about processes *owned by a different user* (i.e., someone with an administrative token). You're not going to be able to do that. All you can do as a non-administrator is get information about *your own* processes. If you want to get information about all of the processes running on the system, your app will need to require elevation to get administrative privileges.

Comment: Okay, thank you Cody for clarification.